# Powershell filtering rows based on latest timestamp

Tags: powershell

I have a massive CSV file with 4 columns of data.  LastSub is a timestamp and each Username has many rows of data.  I want to grab just the most LastSub date for each Section and Username.

| Section | Item | LastSub | Username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA181249 | 6101628935 | 9/27/22 11:52am | 5220107 |
| AA181249 | 6101628935 | 10/12/22 10:00am | 5220107 |
| AA181253 | 6126161526 | 9/20/22 11:52am | 5220107 |
| AA181253 | 6126161526 | 10/14/22 10:53am | 5220107 |

so I'd want the data to come out like this:

| Section | Item | LastSub | Username |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA181249 | 6101628935 | 10/12/22 10:00am | 5220107 |
| AA181253 | 6126161526 | 10/14/22 10:53am | 5220107 |

I've tried various ways of doing this and keep running into problems.  Here's my current code that takes the big data set, filters to the 4 columns above that have dates in the LastSub column.

```
Import-Csv "F:\TLGDRIVE\Schoology Grade Check\Inbound Submissions Date\rawdata\test3.csv"  -Header 'SectNID','SectSchCode','SIS','GraPer','GradeItemID','LastSub','Username','School' |  Where {$_} | Where {$_.LastSub -ne ''} | select -Property 'SectSchCode','GradeItemID','LastSub','Username' 
Foreach-Object {$_.LastSub = [nullable[DateTime]]$_.LastSub; $_}
```

However, when I tried to select only the latest date time for each section/username combination, I get the error:

```
The property 'LastSub' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:2 char:17
>+ Foreach-Object {$_.LastSub = [nullable[DateTime]]$_.LastSub; $_}
>+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

I'm just stuck at finding a way to only grab the most recent date and could use some help.  Thanks!

I was hoping to get this code to work, but I keep getting an error on a null row.

```
Foreach-Object {$_.LastSub = [DateTime]$_.LastSub; $_} 
Group-Object Username | Foreach-Object {$_.Group | Sort-Object 'LastSub' | Select-Object -Last 1} | Export-Csv
```

Thanks in advance!

Update, here's the code with piping the first line that now works.  thank you!

```
Import-Csv "F:\TLGDRIVE\Schoology Grade Check\Inbound Submissions Date\rawdata\test3.csv"  -Header 'SectNID','Section','SIS','GraPer','GradeItemID','LastSub','Username','School' |  Where {$_} | Where {$_.LastSub -ne ''} | select -Property 'Section','GradeItemID','LastSub','Username' |
Group-Object Section | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($group in $_.Group | Group-Object Username) {
        $group.Group | Sort-Object { Get-Date $_.LastSub } -Descending |
                    Select-Object -First 1    
                   }
                    } |  Export-Csv "F:\TLGDRIVE\Schoology Grade Check\Inbound Submissions Date\submissions $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Are you piping the first line to foreach-object?

Comment: It works for me when filling in the missing pipe symbols.